Breaking up python computation to speed up ssh
I'm using a Paramiko connection to execute a handful of commands over ssh. A few (not entirely real) examples to show the idea:
def get_version(conn):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command('ipmitool bla bla')
    result = stdout.readlines()[-1].strip()
    if result == 'the expected value':
        return result
    else:
        return None

def i2c_device_check(conn, bus, addr):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command('i2cdetect ...')
    # check stdout
    return True # or false, whatever        

def get_status(conn, device_type):
    if i2c_device_check(0x10, 0x4):
        if device_type == 'machine1':
            cmd = 'i2cget -f 0 0x10 0x4 0x2b'
        else:
            cmd = 'i2cget -f 0 0x10 0x4 0x3c'
        stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command(cmd)
        # do stuff with stdout
        return stuff
    return None
    

I'm showing here that the ssh commands are interspersed with business logic. There are dozens of these, and the several 10s or 100s of millisecond delay with each exec_command(...) call is adding up, so I'd like to do things in batch mode.
The execution time of the call once it reaches the host is very fast, so that's not the bottleneck.  Parallelizing won't help in this  case because everything gets serialized on the host anyway (eg i2c or ipmi calls), so I'd just be paying overhead for concurrency without any time benefit.
I'd like to build up the logic and the list of commands to call, then send the list at one time so I only have to pay the cost of one exec_command call.
So I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to do things.  If it were just a blind list of commands to send and then store the results, it would be easy, but the logic surrounding each command could be arbitrary.
I've tried pushing the command string to a global var, then using yield to stop the computation for a moment so I can execute the commands, then come back after the execution, and that works for a simple list of commands with minimal logic, but it gets confusing when one of these functions calls another one and if there is a decision to be made based on the results of an ssh command, then the whole batch thing has to stop and start over.
I kind of want something that 'selects' or 'waits' for the command to execute before continuing, while secretly stashing the commands in the background then executing them once they've built up to some threshold.  This way the code can be understood in one view without jumping around a lot.
Is yield the best thing here because it pauses the computation?  or can I use concurrent.futures (maxworker=1) to capture the idea that we're waiting for something to happen?
I'm looking for an approach or philosophy here showing good semantics to capture my intent, not necessarily code examples.

There's little overhead to exec_command(), putting everything in one call is not likely to make much difference.

If you want to speed things up, use multiple connections and multiple threads so they can run concurrently.
